# aligning font awesome icons

Tags: html, css

I understand that there are multiple posts about this but whatever I try doesnt work. I've tried text-align, different layouts, etc. and i have no clue how to fix this.

Here is the code:

```css
.down{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 40px;
    color:white;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.center{
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center" class="small-4 medium-4 large-4 columns">
    <i  class="fa fa-angle-double-down hvr-hang down"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to align in center?

Answer (score 0):

If u want to vertically center the icon, then u should give it line-height equal to the height of the element

Add this to ur **.down** css class `line-height: 50px!important;`

```css
.down{


color:black;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px!important;

/*for demo purpose*/
border:1px solid black;
}


.center{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="text-align: center" class="small-4 medium-4 large-4 columns">
    <i  class="fa fa-angle-double-down hvr-hang down"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using flexbox to easily align horizontally and vertically.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue; /* for visibility purpose only */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="small-4 medium-4 large-4 columns">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down hvr-hang down"></i>
</div>
```